# \hfill not aligning properly in verse environment in memoir

Tags: memoir, verse, poetry, hfill

I'm typesetting a bunch of poetry some lines of which have what are essentially marginal labels, all of which I want to be right justified against the right-hand margin.  When I use \hfill, they do not align.

What can I use other than \hfill to insert an arbitrary amount of whitespace that ensures all of the labels are right-justified?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\hfill\emph{antistrophe 1} \\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
consectetur adipiscing elit.\hfill\emph{strophe 2} \\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
Donec malesuada aliquet cursus.\hfill\emph{antistrophe 2} \\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
Pellentesque vitae dolor a dolor malesuada\hfill\emph{strophe 3} \\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
sodales quis vel arcu. Quisque in varius est.\hfill\emph{antistrophe 3} \\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

And here's the output it generates:

[image: here's the output]

I would like all of the numbers to be lined up with each other, against the right-hand margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a stronger infinity than `\hfill` and also to remove the `\rightmargin`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\versecomment}[1]{%
  \unskip
  \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
  \emph{#1}%
  \hspace*{-\rightmargin}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \versecomment{antistrophe 1} \\
consectetur adipiscing elit.\versecomment{strophe 2} \\
Donec malesuada aliquet cursus.\versecomment{antistrophe 2} \\
Pellentesque vitae dolor a dolor malesuada\versecomment{strophe 3} \\
sodales quis vel arcu. Quisque in varius est.\versecomment{antistrophe 3} \\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, thanks; I did change \hspace*{-\rightmargin} to   \hspace*{+\rightmargin}, because otherwise the comments overlapped with the line numbers.